# Google Bazel ECCN

Tags: bazel, eccn

Can anyone confirm, If this software is classified with ECCN? If yes, please confirm the applicable number.

If not, please kindly answer the following questions so that it can be self-assessed:

1, Does the Software perform any encryption or utilize any encryption processes?  Y/N
2. If the answer is YES to question 1, please indicate if the encryption is coded into the application or separately called (such as using SSL)
3. If the answer is YES to question 1, please indicate what function(s) the cryptography/encryption serves

A, Copyright protection purposes (Includes using a license key/code)
B, User authentication purposes
C, A core part of the functionality such as to encrypt databases
D, To encrypt communications between the software and a host system.

Background information:
An Export Control Classification Number (ECCN) is a specific alpha-numeric code that identifies the level of export control for items e.g. software that are exported from member states of the Wassenaar Arrangement, including the United States. After obtaining the ECCN, the exporter must determine whether an export license is required to export items to certain countries

Comment: Does someone have a feeling that this question is a homework assignment?

Answer (score 2):

I asked my colleagues who specialize in this area and can provide you with this statement regarding Bazel's publicly available open-source code in its current version:

"This publicly available code is not subject to the Export Administration Regulation (EAR) and has no Export Control Classification Number (ECCN)."

Hope this helps.